# IBM login issue. Error BXNUI0303E

Tags: authentication, ibm-cloud

i am trying to login my ibm account to use its iot platform. but its giving error while login.

BXNUI0303E: The account information could not be retrieved because of a problem contacting the business support system. You will be logged out of Bluemix.

Try again later. If you see this message again, go to DOCS and select Troubleshooting for help and support options.

I am trying since last 3 hours.
Can anyone help me.?
Thanks

Comment: Well, did you try what the message said, namely "go to DOCS and select Troubleshooting for help and support options" and contact customer service?

Comment: that doesn't give any fruitfull result.

Comment: What do you mean? What did customer service tell you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I google `ibm BXNUI0303E`, I find these as first results:

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/267171/bxnui0303e-the-account-information-could-not-be-re.html

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/238858/not-able-to-login-from-bluemix-login-screen-bxnui0.html

So, you are not alone, the solution is probably just to wait until they fix the problem.

I also found that this [status page](http://estado.ng.bluemix.net/) lists tons of services as "down" at the moment:[image]

Comment: hoping they fix it very soon :) :)

Answer (score 6):

We are aware of the current issues that are being experienced with Bluemix and are working as quickly as possible to resolve them. We sincerely apologize for the inconvenience.

For more information about the situation, please visit the following URL: https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status

Update - July 2017: Please be aware that the Bluemix Status Page moved. It is now located at the following URL: 
https://console.bluemix.net/status
Use the filter to list the specific category, region, and component information